# javascript alert() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have an Ajax request which in error condition alerts the message returned from server. This works in all browsers except for IE. it shows an empty alert box.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name!='photo_1']").parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find(".label").remove();

    $("input[type=file]").on('change',function(){
        $(this).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/ajax-loader.GIF') no-repeat center center");
        var selectedElement = this;
        var name = $(this).attr('name').toString();
        $('#upload').ajaxSubmit({
            dataType:'json',
            data: {name:name},
            beforeSubmit:function(){
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('input[type=file]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/loading.png') no-repeat center center");
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    $("input[name=" + index + "]").parents('label').find('img').remove();
                    $("input[name=" + index + "]").parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').append("<img src='http://localhost/project/uploads/" + item.NAME +"' width='190px' height='" + Math.floor(190/(item.WIDTH/item.HEIGHT)) + "px' />");
                    $("input[name=" + index + "]").parents('label').find('.thumbnail').css('height','');
                    $("input[name=" + index + "]").parents('label').find('.thumbnail').css('min-height',Math.floor(190/(item.WIDTH/item.HEIGHT)).toString()+"px");
                });
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('input[type=file]').removeAttr('disabled');
                return false;
            },
            error : function(xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"none");
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/upload_a_photo.png') no-repeat center center");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It is there $('#upload').ajaxSubmit({....

Comment: It's a call to ajaxSubmit.
@1linecode: the problem is not the alert but the fact that responseText is not set properly on IE. We need your server-side code. Perhaps it is a charset encoding problem?

Comment: @OMiD, I've used jQuery form plugin. that sends Ajax when the form element's value is changed.

Comment: You have `alert(xhr.responseText);` and blame `alert()`. It's more likely that `xhr.responseText` is either empty or a non-printable value. What do you get with `console.log(`xhr.responseText`)`?

Comment: Quick question, are you sure it went to error?

Comment: @EricT, what do you mean?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, it sends me back my error message:<p>The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width.</p>

Comment: ouch, so it was in error condition. which IE version are you using?

Comment: My guess is that xhr.responseText is empty. Try `alert('Error '+xhr.status+': '+xhr.responseText);` and see if we get any more clues.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, It shows empty string in IE console log. shows LOG:

Comment: @Moob, it says Error0: in alert in either IE 8 & IE 9

Comment: @Moob, in others it alerts:Error 400: <p>The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width.</p>. the 400 code is because I've written it in my serverside code to return that http status

Comment: Problem solved guys. I shouldn't have used a header() with error code 400 in my server side. I don't know why but when I omit it it shows the message in IE

Comment: but still shows Error0: message in alert in IE

Comment: Try adding `$.support.cors = true;` before your ajax call.
I think IE has issues with [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) over localHost